# Firebase - How to whitelist production server IP?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am have having a bit of an issue with an app server I am using to send notifications using the Firebase HTTP API.

The implementation on my development app server works, so apparently all I need to do is whitelist my production app server IP and I'm good to go.

However, I can't for the life of me find out how to do this via the Firebase Console. All guides I have found are for the old console layout, so I am at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A server has a *Sender ID* and a *Server Key*. Make sure your Android *application ID* is registered and that the application issues FCM token for the correct Sender ID.